# Submit Button on Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project where I must have daily inventory entered by multiple locations into Google Sheets. There are up to 85 potential entries so I chose to create it in a spreadsheet instead of Google Forms.

The question that I have is, after data is entered into the Google Sheet, can I add a submit button that will record the data into a Master Sheet so I may generate reports and record the data over time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible.

## Explanation

Google Sheets could be extended by using [Google Apps Scripts](http://www.google.com/script/start). You could insert an image and assign a script to it but also you could use custom menus, dialogs, side bars and triggers.

## Reference

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)