# Is there a way to create a custom button in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, button, google-apps-script, uibutton

Here is my code, and where I want to add a custom button:

```
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result_1 = ui.prompt(
    'Enter task and associated subtasks, if any:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL); #ADD CUSTOM BUTTON HERE
  //var button = result_1.getSelectedButton();
  var task = result_1.getResponseText();
  var result_2 = ui.prompt(
    'Enter priority, based on when you will begin the task in a sequence of tasks:',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var button = result_2.getSelectedButton();
  var priority = result_2.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    ui.alert('Task added.\nTask: '+task+'\nPriority: ' + priority);
  }
}
```

I can not find a way to create a custom button. I came across this webpage: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service, and apparently there used to be a createButton method, but this interface has already been deprecated.

Is there a work-around? I don't want to create an image of a button and link it to the script.

Comment: Are you looking to add a button to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit Button on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306503/submit-button-on-google-sheets)

Comment: You need to use HTML Service. [Link to documentation - custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)