# Is there a way to make a custom alert button using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Ok, first things first, I KNOW this is a duplicate and I will lose reputation for this but if you want to visit the question it's [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108588/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-custom-button-in-google-apps-script), but there isn't an answer for that question so... But anyways, judging by the title, I am creating an add-on where an alert alerts the user the credits of the add-on and then there is a `launch` button. Here is the code:

```
function onOpen(){
  var alert = DocumentApp.getUi().alert("...credits...", "Launch")
}
```

So at first, I though you can just do that but then it threw me an error and I apparently, you have to use a button set which is lame. So I tried searching the web but I couldn't find it so I decided to ask Stack Overflow. So please, if someone would help me or show me a "**code hack**".



EDIT: Oh ya, so if this question takes to much of my reputation, I will remove it.

Comment: The comment from Alan Wells on your linked question mentions using HTML Service, have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function alertWithLaunchButton() {
  var html='.....credits....<input type="button" value="Launch" onClick="launch();" />';
  html+='<script>function launch(){google.script.run.launch();google.script.host.close();}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Launch Alert');
}

function launch() {
  return;
}
```